# bar graph in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

i need to take user input and make a very simple bar graph from it in vb.net. anyone have suggestions on an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed - you didn't specifiy framewrok version - web or windows app. But [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en)
is a good free one for 3.5 framework web or windows apps.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify a framework but I'm guessing that you're using winforms?

What you're looking for is a chart / bar control.  By default WinForms doesn't have great bar / chart controls.  This site has a breakdown of the various add ons Microsoft released for WinForms and ASP.Net in the area of chart controls

- http://blogs.msdn.com/magreer/archive/2008/10/24/microsoft-chart-control-for-winforms-and-asp-net-now-available.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have been very please with [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Sample_Graphs) for .net 2.0. I use it for both webforms and winForms.